# Displaying files from resources folder and making them downloadable

Tags: php

I am trying to create a sort of download list where I grab all the files from the resources folder.. my php file is in a different folder to that..

and then I want to make them like links so people can download those files

I tried this:

```
<?php
    foreach(glob('*.*') as $filename) {
        echo $filename."<br />";
    }
?>
```

However I don't know how to grab files from my resources folder or make them downloadable :(

Cheers!

Comment: Is the resources folder web-accessible? If it is you can create `<a>` elements and build their `href` parameters to point to each file; if it's not you will have to build a downloader script which basically will send the right HTTP headers then serve the file through `readfile`.

Comment: so you tried echo'ing the names of files. ok... and what did not work about that? what are you trying to do besides echo'ing a filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan the directory and grab the the files with scandir

```
    $dir    = '/tmp';
    $files1 = scandir($dir);

   //Check if file is not . OR ..

    $ignore = array(".", "..");
    foreach($files1 as $key => $value){
      if (!in_array($value, $ignore)) {
        echo $value;
      }
    }
```

For more information read : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

In order to make a downloadable link I would like to know what kind of files you want to download.

Comment: First of all thanks! :D

Secondly however, how do i get rid of the first '.' and '..' objects in the array? and how would I make these objects downloadable?

Comment: Downloadable files will include word documents, pdf files, text files and images

Comment: When I use your code above nothing displays even though I have images in the resources folder?

Comment: Ahh I was thinking that I just wasn't too sure! Thanks :D but how would I go about making these files downloadable?

Comment: I was able to use a .htaccess call: AddType application/octet-stream .jpg .png .pdf .doc .docx .mp4 .etc

Comment: Nice, glad to help :)